# Reading data from file into 2 arrays

Tags: c, ubuntu

im trying to read data from a file the file setup is like this:

```
3050 76
2030 60
1600 70
2222 50
2430 60
2800 50
0 0
```

the first number represents a student ID, the second number represents the student's grade
when the program reaches  0 0, it should stop reading from the file

here is an example of program, its not reading from the file because an error shows up called SEGMENTATION FAULT. i'm using ubuntu, this is were this error occurs

```
// this is the grading sorting program for part one


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 50

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE* fp; // file pointer, points to the file
    char file_name[32]; // store file name

    int ID[SIZE];
    int grade[SIZE];

    int a,b; // index variables

    int student_id, grades;

    // opening file by asking the user for the file name
    printf("Enter the name of the file containing the grades\n");
    scanf("%s",file_name);

    fp=fopen("file_name", "r");

    /*fp = fopen("grades.txt", "r");*/

    // read in data into the arrays
    for (a = 0; a <= SIZE; a++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%d", &student_id);
        ID[a] = student_id;

        for(b = 0; b <= SIZE; b++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d", &grades);
            grade[b] = grades;
        }

        if(ID[a] == 0 && grade[b] == 0)
            break;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like homework

Comment: Is the filename longer than 32 characters? Also, if this is homework, you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an excellent opportunity to get acquainted with `gdb`. Since you are on ubuntu, it should be installed by default.

Compile your program with `-gdb3` and load it into gdb:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
```

Run it using `r` and gdb will show you where the segfault occurs, examine your variables from there using the `print` statement.

```
$ gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from /home/user/tmp/SO/bytes/a.out...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/user/tmp/SO/bytes/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080483a4 in main () at sf.c:7
7       *p = 2;
(gdb) print p
$1 = (int *) 0x0
```

Comment: what do you mean compile and run with  - gdb3

Comment: GDB is a command line debugger.  The Debugger is a tool to help you fix programs and allow you to run them one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of things that are off here, such as:

- The filename is likely not right - `fopen("file_name",...` will always look to open a file called "`filename`"
- You are creating the ID and grade arrays with a length of 50 (SIZE) - in C, this means that the array indices range from 0 to 49, but both your a and b for loops go from 0 to 50.
- You aren't doing any sanity checks on the output from fscanf, nor checking to see if you can actually open the file.

I would suggest reading up on C arrays, string handling and file I/O operations - there is a wealth of tutorials that you can find via Google.

Answer (score 1):

**First**
this is incorrect

```
fp=fopen("file_name", "r");
```

probably you meant

```
fp=fopen(file_name, "r");
```

**Second**
You don't exit from this loop before you have read an integer for SIZE times

```
for(b = 0; b < SIZE; b++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d", &grades);
            grade[b] = grades;
        }
```

You don't have to make a loop for this: I think

```
fscanf(fp,"%d", &grades);
```

instead, is all you really need to read the grades.

**Third** 
Remember to always test the return code from the fscanf() and the fopen()

Example:

```
if ((fp=fopen(file_name,"r"))==NULL) exit(-9);
do {
    if (fscanf(fp,"%d",&(ID[a]))!=1) break;
    if (fscanf(fp,"%d",&(grade[a]))!=1) break; 
}
while((grade[a]!=0) && (ID[a++]!=0));
```

Answer (score 0):

One hint you are reading to many values. You have a nested for loop that will attempt to Read Size * Size Entities.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably this part:

```
fp=fopen("file_name", "r");
```

You want to use the variable file_name instead:

```
fp=fopen(file_name, "r");
```

To make your program less error-prone, you should always check that the file has been opened successfully:

```
fp=fopen("file_name", "r");
if (!fp)
  return -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't solve the problem , but change   for (a = 0; a <= SIZE; a++)
to   for (a = 0; a < SIZE; a++)

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file with a name of "file_name", which is likely not the file scanned in from the command line.

To fix this remove the quotes on the line

```
   fp=fopen("file_name", "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner loop, and you're reading from something like "~/file_name", this probably doesn't exist so fp will be NULL (which you don't check for) and so any attempts to use it will cause a crash.